# prevent empty gaps with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap, is it possible to prevent gaps like this:
(without making all heights the same, that would be just filling gaps..)

[image]

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
            aaaaaaa<br />
            aaaaaaa<br />
            aaaaaaa<br />
            aaaaaaa<br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
            bbbbbbbb<br />
            bbbbbbbb<br />
            bbbbbbbb<br />
            bbbbbbbb<br />
            bbbbbbbb<br />
            bbbbbbbb<br />
            bbbbbbbb<br />
            bbbbbbbb<br />
            bbbbbbbb<br />
            bbbbbbbb<br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
            cccccccc<br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
            dddddddd<br />
            dddddddd<br />
            dddddddd<br />
            dddddddd<br />
            dddddddd<br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
            eeeeeeee<br />
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

here a jsfiddle to work with:

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1438/

Comment: your question is not clear. where do you want to eliminate gaps ?

Comment: No, you need a plugin to make it happen. Something like  http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @RahulSambari like under the aaaaaaaaa, there is a big white rectangle. I would prefer if ccccccc moves up there.

Comment: do you have jsfiddle or something which we can work on ?

Comment: @RahulSambari sure mate: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1438/

Comment: remember that bootstrap columns are nestable,

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping the colored `div` into two columns and stack them among themselves.

[image: Demo]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6" style="padding: 0;">
            <div style="background: red; padding: 0 15px;">
                aaaaaaa<br />
                aaaaaaa<br />
                aaaaaaa<br />
                aaaaaaa<br />
            </div>
            <div style="background: blue; padding: 0 15px;">
                cccccccc<br />
            </div>
            <div style="background: yellow; padding: 0 15px;">
                eeeeeeee<br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6" style="padding: 0;">
            <div style="background: green; padding: 0 15px;">
                bbbbbbbb<br />
                bbbbbbbb<br />
                bbbbbbbb<br />
                bbbbbbbb<br />
                bbbbbbbb<br />
                bbbbbbbb<br />
                bbbbbbbb<br />
                bbbbbbbb<br />
                bbbbbbbb<br />
                bbbbbbbb<br />
            </div>
            <div style="background: purple; padding: 0 15px;">
                dddddddd<br />
                dddddddd<br />
                dddddddd<br />
                dddddddd<br />
                dddddddd<br />
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

You can see a working demo on http://jsfiddle.net/urc8yev5/

For optimization consider using css classes for elements who have same styles in common.

Comment: That only works proper if I know the length of the divs before i start so I know how to divide the columns.